# Exception thrown: write access violation. this was 0xDDDDDDDD

Tags: c++, aes, access-violation, crypto++

I'm trying to encrypt a string using AES encryption provided by Crypto++ library API, version 5.6.0, linked statically

```
string AESEncryptor::encrypt(const string& plain)
{
    string ciphertext_buffer;

    // Hex decode symmetric key:
    HexDecoder decoder;
    decoder.Put((byte *)PRIVATE_KEY, 32 * 2);
    decoder.MessageEnd();
    word64 size = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
    char *decoded_key = new char[size];
    decoder.Get(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(decoded_key), size);

    // Generate Cipher, Key, and CBC
    byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH], iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    StringSource(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(decoded_key), true, 
        new HashFilter(*(new SHA256), new ArraySink(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH)));
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption Encryptor(key, sizeof(key), iv);
    StringSource(plain, true, 
        new StreamTransformationFilter(Encryptor, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(ciphertext_buffer))));
    return ciphertext_buffer;
}
```

On the function exit I'm receiving the following exception, while trying to call the std::string move constructor to return the value:

> Exception thrown: write access violation. this was 0xDDDDDDDD.

Looked like StringSink "owns" returned std::string some way and deletes it before trying to return, however I tried to assign it to another std::string and got the same exception.

Same exception appears while returning any other string, so it seems memory corrupted some way

Comment: The documentation explicitly says StringSink doesn't own the output string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> StringSource(plain, true, 
>     new StreamTransformationFilter(Encryptor,
>         new HexEncoder(new StringSink(ciphertext_buffer))));
>
> return ciphertext_buffer;
> ```

This code is mostly OK, but you should avoid the anonymous declarations.

> ```
> Exception thrown: write access violation. this was 0xDDDDDDDD.
> ```

[0xDDDDDDDD is the "dead memory" bit pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195)
There's quite a few issues with the code, and its hard to say which is causing you to use the dead memory. Maybe `PRIVATE_KEY` is smaller than `32 * 2` bytes?

You should do four things:

- Upgrade to [Crypto++ 5.6.4](http://cryptopp.com/) (5.6.0 is from 2009)
- Turn on memory checking with flags like `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF` (see [`test.cpp` and `main`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/test.cpp#L139) for an example)
- Stop using anonymous declarations (I've seen destructors run too soon because of them)
- Use [EAX Mode](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode) sample code from the [Crypto++ wiki](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/) as a starting point

---

> ```
> // Generate Cipher, Key, and CBC
> byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH], iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
> StringSource(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(decoded_key), true, 
>     new HashFilter(*(new SHA256), new ArraySink(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH)));
> ```

Use [HKDF](https://cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_h_k_d_f.html) from Crypto++ 5.6.3 and above.

---

> ```
> memset(iv, 0x00, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
> ```

I believe this destroys some of CBC's security properties. You should use an [Authenticated Encryption](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode. It relieves you of some of the details, like generating random IVs. It also has better security properties than CBC alone.

Comment: We can quibble about whether that should read "some" or "most" of CBC's security properties - but definitely always using an IV of zero is a no-no.  In particular, it means that if two plain-texts have  identical first blocks, then the first blocks of the cipher text will be identical too - which may be more than enough for an attacker to gain meaningful information from.

Comment: Migration to Crypto++ 5.6.4 and new API helped, thanks